# Importing tables from Salesforce to SQl server

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008, msbi

Is it possible to Extract all tables of sales force into SQL server Like import in SQL server or SSIS

Comment: https://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can achieve this in SSIS. Use the Task Factory Salesforce component. 
In your scenario, use TF Salesforce Source and OleDB Destination.

Task Factory: https://pragmaticworks.com/Products/Task-Factory/Feature/Salesforce-SSIS

It is free to use on SSDT/Visual Studio.
Hope it helps.

Comment: i know this but i am talking about importing all tables at a time note one by one.

Answer (score 0):

this sounds possible using Deepak's solution.

What I would recommend is getting a list of each table name, then use a recordset destination to populate an object variable. That object variable would then be used by the foreach loop to set the list to be pulled from salesforce.

This *could* be the solution you're looking for.